# Does powershellScheduler task run on web dbs?

Tags: scheduled-tasks

If I publish powershell task scheduler item to target dbs...will the task the task run separately on all dbs?

Answer (score 2):

Tasks do not run on databases, the tasks run on the Sitecore instance. If your Task Scheduler is enabled on your Content Delivery instance to use your `web` database, then it will execute any tasks that are configured.

*But*, Sitecore PowerShell Extensions is *not* enabled on Content Delivery instances by default. The default configuration only enables SPE for the `Standalone`, `ContentManagement`, and `XMCloud` server roles. So unless you have changed that for your implementation, the `tasks` integration will not run on a `ContentDelivery` server role.

Comment: Hi Richard, I have this powershell schedular item scheduled on master db  the same got published to web dbs....still it will consider it as separate task?  I.e one of master db and one of web db?

Comment: yes - they are separate tasks